# Alternativa para o enterprise architect

Tags: engenharia-de-software

Alguém sabe alguma ferramenta para diagramação de classes como o EA? Não precisa ser tão completa preciso somente de diagramas de classes, e ela teria que rodar no ubuntu.

Comment: As respostas deixam claro que é difícil responder sem incorrer em GTKY (legal saber o que você gosta) que talvez seja o principal motivo para existir o fechamento baseado em opiniões.

Comment: O Open Office não tem?

Comment: Porque fechar essa pergunta? Tenho certeza as respostas podem ajudar várias pessoas.

Comment: @FábioLemosElizandro Não pode. O SOpt não é um repositório de links e opiniões. As informações contidas aqui passam a falsa sensação de que as informações são relevantes para ajudar alguém decidir alguma coisa com critério mas na verdade são só alguns usuários dizendo o que eles gostam. Com o tempo você entenderá como o SOpt é diferente de um fórum onde as pessoas colocam informações sem se preocupar com a relevância dela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O [StarUML](http://staruml.io/) é uma ótima ferramenta, muito completa e free.

Possui recursos de modelagem UML, é extensível e possui um UX muito agradável.

Para utilizar o StarUML no Ubuntu, será necessário utilizar o Wine

> Em Applications, selecione Ubuntu Software Center
>   Pesquise por Wine se você ainda não o tem instalado
>   Instale o Wine
>   depois basta fazer o download e executar conforme abaixo
>   wget http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/staruml/staruml-5.0-with-cm.exe
>   wget http://kegel.com/wine/winetricks sh winetricks vcrun6 msxml3
>   wine staruml-5.0-with-cm.exe
>
> Isto irá instalar o starUML no seu sistema e rodar com Wine.

Fonte: http://jefferyhaynes.net/2009/12/12/getting-staruml-working-on-ubuntu-9-10/

Comment: Parece que não tem para ubuntu =S

Comment: Encontrei uma ferramente que parece legal [genmymodel](http://www.genmymodel.com/)

Comment: Tenho interesse sim =) pode colocar que eu escolho como resposta

Comment: @FábioLemosElizandro Feito!

Answer (score 2):

Como sugestão, recomendo fortemente o [Astah*](http://astah.net/).

Ele tem build nativo para **Linux** (**Mac OS** e **Windows** também) e está a muito tempo no mercado. Começou como o Jude e depois mudou de nome para Astah*.

A versão **Community** que é grátis e atende a muitos casos onde se precisa apenas de um diagrama e que possa exportar como imagem.

E possui os seguintes diagramas:

1. Classe
2. Casos de uso
3. Sequência
4. Atividade
5. Comunicação
6. Estados
7. Componente
8. Deployment
9. Estrutura composta
10. Objetos e Pacotes

Existe uma versão **Pro** e também para estudantes, cheguei a conseguir uma vez apenas enviando um comprovante de inscrição. Nessa versão existem 16 tipos de diagramas, já é possível exportar código e também fazer engenharia reversa.

Answer (score 1):

Uso o [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/), que [possui instalação para o Linux](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/12/14/6043_linuxandunix.html). É a ferramenta de UML mais completa que eu conheço.

Possui versão Community e Pro.